# Incorrect results in calculations with decimal values with four digits after dot

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that returns the result of multiplications using decimal values (four digits after dot).

But, in some conditions, the result is a mess like this:

```
3.9050 * 9 = 35.144999999999996.
```

What should I do to normalize those results?

Comment: Must be answered a million times, but couldn't find one quickly. This link is pretty good though: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html

Comment: @wvdz close -> duplicate -> math broken -> first result

Comment: Answered pretty well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: What is expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.toFixed(numberOfDecsYouWant)`

```js
var num = 3.9050 * 9;
console.log(num);  //35.144999999999996
console.log(num.toFixed(4))  //35.1450
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Please guys, try to understand better the questions and the possible existing answers before criticize and mark as duplicated, cause I've searched hard before ask e I didn't find any answer as good as I get here by kpucha.

Comment: They think you are asking why, but obviiously you are asking for a fix... they flagged as duplicated with an answer of why instead of how.